# Xpath: Normalize-space on final node

Tags: xpath

Basic Xpath question: I'm using desktop app to scrape webpage for numeric dollar amount found in span tag, under the path.

```
//div[contains(@class,'ProductDetailInfoBlock-pricing-amount')]/span
```

$35.12 (only thing within span) comes back surrounded with assorted blank spaces and 9 line breaks.  How do I apply normalize-space() to this result found in span?

The application doesn't allow:

```
normalize-space(//div[contains(@class,'ProductDetailInfoBlock-pricing-amount')]/span)
```

How its done- Applying it to /span?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
normalize-space(//div[contains(@class,'ProductDetailInfoBlock-pricing-amount')]/span/text())
```

just add `/text()` in the end, as you are trying to normalize it, not the node)